# Carousel VueJS - back button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, carousel, back-button

[Carousel VueJS (code)][1]

[image: Screen captures showing steps described]

I am sending you my screen captures with the code attached for a VueJS carousel that I am working on:
Any idea on how to remove the `BACK` button on step 1/3?

Comment: Can you please provide your code ? Without it, it is hard to say.